# Makefile linker error

Tags: c++, makefile

I seem to be going from one problem to the next ever since I decided to organize my code into subdirectories. The problems are naturally arising from the Makefile. So here's what I've currently got:

```
UNAME := $(shell uname)

# Directories
SOURCEDIR = src/
BUILDDIR = build/

# Compiler options
CC = clang++
DEBUG = -g
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)

# Files
SRC = $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)*.cpp) $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)**/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(SRC:$(SOURCEDIR)%.cpp=$(BUILDDIR)%.o)

ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
    LIBS = -lglfw3 -framework OpenGL -lglew -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation -framework ApplicationServices -framework Foundation -framework AppKit 
    BUILDDIR = ./build/osx/
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
    LIBS = -lglfw -lGL -lGLEW
    BUILDDIR = ./build/linux/
endif

# Build target
TARGET = test

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $? -o $(TARGET) $(LIBS)

$(OBJS): $(BUILDDIR)%.o : $(SOURCEDIR)%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)*.o $(BUILDDIR)**/*.o $(TARGET)
```

I was really glad when it actually compiled everything! Except when I made a change to a file, and tried to `make` it again, it spat this at me:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Thing is, when I `make` it once more, it works just fine. The problem seems to be with resolving dependencies? And for that, I need to specify a `VPATH`? Well, that's the closest I've gotten, except trying to specify a VPATH hasn't made a difference. I'm probably specifying it incorrectly, or then I'm taking the wrong approach to this.

I'm pretty inexperienced when it comes to Makefiles, so I'd really appreciate some guidance!

Comment: What do you get if you add `-v` to the invocation like the error says? I'm betting the problem is your use of `$?` in the link command instead of `$^`. You are only telling it to link newer prereqs not the full set of prereqs.

Comment: Etan is right.  `$?` is wrong.  I don't have any idea why it would work the second time.  You should look at the link line make prints and make sure it makes sense.  Another point: your use of `**` is useless here.  That's a special globbing format which is only supported by certain shells.  It's not supporte by GNU make's wildcard function, and it's almost certainly not supported by `/bin/sh` on your system which is what make uses to run commands.

Comment: I was assuming that clang was deleting the target when it failed to link and thus the newer-than check succeeded correctly the second time.

Comment: Thanks Etan! That really was the issue. I wouldn't have gotten that on my own, the syntax is still quite alien to me. Not to mention when you've been staring at the same thing for long enough, it all becomes a big glob of text...

Comment: And MadScientist, as for the <code>**</code>, I was browsing through some other answers here on stackoverflow, where it was recommended as a means for looking through all subdirectories, as opposed to one layer deep. I don't even need such functionality, so as per your suggestion, I'll be removing it. Thanks to the two of you, sorry I can't upvote your comments, don't have enough points myself, yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Etan Reisner for the solution. The problem was with the difference between `$?` and `$^`. Here's the fixed version:

```
UNAME := $(shell uname)

# Directories
SOURCEDIR = src/
BUILDDIR = build/

# Compiler options
CC = clang++
DEBUG = -g
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)

# Files
SRC = $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)*.cpp) $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)*/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(SRC:$(SOURCEDIR)%.cpp=$(BUILDDIR)%.o)

ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
    LIBS = -lglfw3 -framework OpenGL -lglew -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation -framework ApplicationServices -framework Foundation -framework AppKit 
    BUILDDIR = ./build/osx/
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
    LIBS = -lglfw -lGL -lGLEW
    BUILDDIR = ./build/linux/
endif

# Build target
TARGET = test

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $^ -o $(TARGET) $(LIBS)

$(OBJS): $(BUILDDIR)%.o : $(SOURCEDIR)%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)*.o $(BUILDDIR)*/*.o $(TARGET)
```